# How to get order id after an order is saved using Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am trying to get id of an order whenever an order is saved. I want to send it as an email using webform submission. However, I am unable to find any hook or a way to save order whenever an order is saved Drupal Commerce. I have looked at hook_commerce_order_presave ,but it is invoked before an order is saved.  Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Commerce don't define a specific hook for that. But since the commerce order is an entity, you can use [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) and [hook_entity_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7).

They both have a $type that you can test to see if is an order and a $entity with info if its a new one.

=)

Comment: And, I found these guys with the same question... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91637/what-is-the-hook-when-a-commerce-order-is-updated